# looking for internet cafe software

Tags: wireless-networking, administration

I'm looking for software for a customer which runs a little hotel.
They installed WLAN which is accessible from each room, and I need billing/admin software for that.

It should be possible to define eg. WEP-keys for each room, detect online time (maybe also data-capacity), similar to a phone system.

Anyone can recommend good (maybe even free) software for that purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one for you that you can consider. And also, you might not find anything Legit AND free for internet coffee that provided billable internet access ;)

http://www.antamedia.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Easyhotspot](http://easyhotspot.inov.asia/) is software based on the Ubuntu OS that's meant for running a hotspot. However, I think it'll suit your purpose wonderfully. Users connect to the WLAN and login using credentials. It can be limited by bandwidth, usage and time limits. It contains both invoice billing and pre-paid voucher support.

It's a all-in-one package that runs from a liveCD No need to install different servers, just one computer, this software and a normal router.

Easyhotspot contains all this:

[image: Easyhotspot]

Schematical set-up:

[image]

Comment: Good one, free and Legit! But, what it is, is what it is!

Comment: @r0ca - Too bad people downvote just because my answer's better? =) Not even mentioning why in a comment ;)

Comment: Better, that's not the point. In the FAQ, it's says that downvoting is good when the answer is not appropriate and not related to the question. My answer was related!!! But my opinion did not "fit" with yours. So that's why you downvote...

Comment: @r0ca Is that a reason to take revenge and downvote me as well? Just because my opinion doesn't stroke with yours... You could've just commented me using @blood so I'd take notice. Just taking out "And also, you might not find anything Legit AND free for internet coffee that provided billable internet access ;)" would've made me change my mind and remove your downvote.

Comment: What? You are asking me to do what you did not? Ok, ok, stop crying! I'll upvote one your question/answer!

Comment: @r0ca - Whaha thanks but that's not what I meant, I thought you downvoted this answer...

Comment: Ok, let's skip this sh|t

Comment: @r0ca fine with me ;) Sorry if I unjustly blamed you =)

Comment: @BloodPhilia are you getting paid by Easyhotspot? Bad form to downvote other viable answers just because they aren't yours. Some of the other answers may have features that make them worth considering too, even if they aren't free. (ie. not requiring Ubuntu)

Comment: @ghoppe - Whaha, only wish I was... I'm not downvoting because they're not mine. In fact, I only downvoted the answer of dickysofa. I mentioned -1 in that comment. My comments made to their answers is just to show the asker some of the cons of those solutions.

Comment: @ghoppe - By the way EasyHotspot doesn't require Ubuntu, it's actually an OS build on Ubuntu. It requires next to no configuration at all. You might be right though, maybe I should slow down on the downvotes and cut everyone some slack... =)

Answer (score 1):

I would look in to the [Coova project](http://coova.org/).  It should include everything you need to run your own hotspot - all you need is a wireless access point that will run OpenWRT, and a server to run your RADIUS and web servers.  All of this is free (open source, even), and I've used some of its components in the past as part of large-scale commercial wireless systems and can vouch that at least the parts we used were pretty stable.  You might have to roll your sleeves up a little and learn a bit about RADIUS and such, but I think it's as painless a process as you're going to find, short of hiring someone to do it for you.

Comment: Easyhotspot does this all without al the hassle, it's an all-in-one solution that bundles all the software you just mentioned.

Comment: @BloodPhilia Seriously, you're going to downvote everybody else because you like your own answer better?  I don't think anybody else here was giving an abusive or technically incorrect answer, man.

Comment: Read the comments below my own answer... This has long been resolved, now stop crying about it already.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://oneroof.com - free as in beer!